# Ajax: updatepanel / timer takes focus from my dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, updatepanel, dotnetnuke

I use a timer and updatepanel to show clock in my page. using this codes in my aspx:

```
<%@ Control language="C#" Inherits="Mosi.Modules.Clock.ViewClock" CodeFile="ViewClock.ascx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<asp:Timer ID="Tmrclk" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Tmrclk_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updpanelclk" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Tmrclk" EventName="Tick">
    </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblclk" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this code  in my aspx.cs file:

```
    protected void Tmrclk_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblclk.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

I use this code as a module in dotnetnuke CMS and it works! but when in dotnetnuke I choose a control panel dropdownlist this ajax code cause the dropdownlist unfocused and close.

how can I maintain focus on this dropdownlist.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the dropdown also inside an updatepanel? The forced postback of the timer will probably update that panel too.

Comment: No the dropdownlist is out of updatepanel and load from another control in my CMS

Comment: dotnetnuke may be wrapping the module in its own update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Javascript to show and update your time instead of ajax. I think this would be a better option for your module. Then you dont have to worry about ajax at all. Please see this link below for an example.

[Display Date and Time in Javascript](http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-7-display-date-and-time-in-javascript-real-time-clock-javascript-date-time.html)